# Invalid syntax when trying to map(lambda..)

Tags: python, lambda

I'm writing a function that loops through a list of numbers, and returns a list of the sums of each number's divisors. I'm trying to trim my function down a little, and learn `map(lambda..)` at the same time.

```
def DoWork(nums):
    sums = []
    for n in nums:
        divisors = []
        map(lambda i: divisors.append(i) if not (n%i), range(1,n+1))
        sums.append(sum(divisors))
    return sums
```

I'm getting a syntax error though, regarding the first `,` in the `map()` line.

Comment: Lambda functions are not like in C++ where you can actually capture variables...

Comment: What should `lambda i: divisors.append(i) if not (n%i)` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, we use `map()` in situations where we have a sequence of things [1] and want to transform it into another sequence -- of the same length -- by applying a function to each element.

You can still use it to find the sum of divisors, but I would argue that it's not the most suitable tool for that.

Instead, let me show you how we can apply `map` and `lambda` to your problem by looking at it from a slightly different angle.

First of all, let's rewrite your function to use a list comprehension:

```
def DoWork(nums):
    sums = []
    for n in nums:
        divisors = [i for i in range(1, n+1) if not n % i]
        sums.append(sum(divisors))
    return sums
```

Now observe that the `divisors` list is unnecessary and can eliminated:

```
def DoWork(nums):
    sums = []
    for n in nums:
        sums.append(sum(i for i in range(1, n+1) if not n % i))
    return sums
```

Now we can easily transform the entire function into a single call to `map()`:

```
def DoWork(nums):
    return map(lambda n: sum(i for i in range(1, n+1) if not n % i), nums)
```

[1] `map()` can also be used to transform *multiple* sequences -- generally of the same length -- into a single sequence by applying the same function repeatedly across the input sequences.

Answer (score 2):

A python `lambda` does not work that way. It is should be a simple substitute for a function that takes a  value and returns another value. You can not have `if` conditions floating in it.

```
updated_range = filter(lambda x: not n%x, range(1,n+1))
map(lambda i: divisors.appens(i), updated_range)
#The above code is a bad style. See below!
```

**Note**: Typically, `lambdas` do not modify an external state. It is considered a bad style to call `divisors.append(..)`

Improved version #1:

```
updated_range = filter(lambda x: not n%x, range(1,n+1))
map(lambda i: divisors.append(i), updated_range)
```

Improved version #2 (fixing the lambda that doesn't modify external state):

```
updated_range = filter(lambda x: not n%x, range(1,n+1))
divisors = map(lambda i: i, updated_range)
#(lambda i: i) is an identity function: returns whatever we give it.
#Sort of useless, though.
```

Improved version #3 (More pythonic!):

```
divisors = [x for x in range(1, n+1) if not n%x]
```

Comment: ... and, taking into account that `lambda i: i` does nothing, the last line is also redundant.

Comment: Yes, I know, that was for the OP to follow a line of thought.

Comment: `You can not have if conditions floating in it.` -- Can you explain @Buffalo Rabor's answer, wrt this claim?

Comment: @BuffaloRabor's expression is valid. Let me rephrase by saying that lambdas should contain expressions that return a certain value. `true_val if condition else false_val` is a valid python expression that returns either `true_val` or `false_val`. Syntactically, such expression must also be accompanied with an `else` -- which was missing in your original question. Regardless, there are better ways to do what you are doing as I have outlined in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is rising from incomplete 'if not' logic, where an 'else' clause is required.

```
def DoWork(nums):
    sums = []
    for n in nums:
        divisors = []
        map(lambda i: divisors.append(i) if not (n%i) else 1, range(1,n+1))
        sums.append(sum(divisors))
    return sums
```

error free execution...

```
DoWork(range(0,10))
[0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 12, 8, 15, 13]
```